# Meteor publish/subscribe error

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, reactjs

---

Here are my files:
tasks.js

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import { check } from 'meteor/check';

export const Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');

if(Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish('tasks', function tasksPublication() {
        return Tasks.find();
    });
}
```

TasksList.jsx

```
import Tasks from '../../api/tasks.js';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
...
TasksList.propTypes = {
    tasks: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
}
...
export default createContainer(() => {
    Meteor.subscribe('tasks');
    return {
        tasks: Tasks.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}}).fetch(),
    };
}, TasksList);
```

Server: main.js

```
import '../imports/api/tasks';
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Tasks.find is not a function
```

at this line

```
tasks: Tasks.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}}).fetch(),
```

I can't where's the error, everything looks normal for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it:
It should be:

```
import {Tasks} from '../../api/tasks.js';
```